# HYBRIS : Angular Integration with Hybris

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud

I would like to understand a very important point.
there are hybris projects that use angular in frontend. So we are going to create angular components and at the angular application we will add a proxy like this one to do the mapping and call the right service

```
{
"/hybris/*": {
   "target": "<your sap nw gateway host>:<your sap nw gateway port>",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel" : "debug"
}
}
```

But how are we going to manage these components at the level of hybris? in cms cockpits for example

Answer (score 4):

Hybris has own strategy for UI, some details are in this [blog](https://hybristech.wordpress.com/2017/05/01/concept-of-page-slots-components-and-content-slots/). Hybris using own UI with integrated with cms cockpits, assisted services, online edit, customer based component customization, etc. Every component designed separately, and render in div on ui using jsp.

You can use angular as js engine in ui but, it is hard to use angular component as hybris component (because of existing functionality not support it). hybris has rest api, may be you can develop own angular project using these rest services but solution is not feasible. Because, a lot of ootb advantages (i give some of them below) will not work.

You can get existing rest api functions from https://url:9002/rest/v2/swagger-ui.html if it was enabled.

**Update 29.10.2018:** SAP announce Spartacus store front, which support component driven UI with Angular. It will support smart edit, asissted service. Details are in this [blog](https://hybrismart.com/2018/10/28/pwa-and-sap-spartacus-overview/)

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Hybris SAP starts to implement a 'single page' frontend for the accelerator. So there is a concept to change the normal frontend (jsp, javascript, css) with another one like Angular.

Just search in the hybris wiki. Here are some links:

- https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/be10de903610471981d3bdfe168940b6.html

Here the important parts

> **b2cangularaddon AddOn**
>   SAP Hybris Commerce Accelerator includes an Angular proof of concept implementation on some pages in the B2C storefronts. This proof of concept highlights what is possible using Angular for a Single Page Application.
>
> **Angular AddOn**
>   The Angular application is entirely self-contained in a new AddOn named b2cangularaddon, which is included in the b2c_acc_plus recipe. The AddOn includes two extensions: angularancillary and angulartestancillary. The AddOn approach was used to allow the Angular application to be isolated from Accelerator and installed as required. Note that the AddOn is installed when using the b2c_acc_plus recipe.
>
> A new component named AngularScriptComponent allows the Angular application to be embedded by assigning it to a page slot. Disabling an existing component and enabling the AngularScriptComponent swaps the existing functionality out for the Angular version both during setup and runtime.
>
> As of 6.6, SAP Hybris no longer includes third-party npm-related JavaScript libraries in SAP Hybris Commerce. This impacts the b2cangularaddon AddOn, which uses these libraries. To enable full build and test capabilities for this AddOn, you must download the required libraries through npm.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but i don't have acces to help :(